Are potential employers "letting me down gently" by giving less than truthful reasons for "rejection"?
I graduated from college earlier this year, and began job searching around a year and a half ago (sometime early last summer). I have submitted on the order of thousands of job applications since then, and have lost track of the number interviews I've attended. At this point, I get roughly 1 to 5 interviews per week, with a substantial subset resulting in at least one follow-up interview, technical assessment, case study, or similar. Most of these interviews, at least from my perspective, go fairly well.
Regrettably, the vast majority of these applications have led nowhere promising. A subset of six, however, have  followed oddly similar trajectories leading to nowhere.
These six jobs have all been entry-level research software engineering jobs at well-regarded universities. The interview process for each spanned several months, with the most recent starting in late August and ending today. I was subject to at least four virtual interviews for each, and for two attended in-person interviews which required flying across the country at my expense. Each required that I complete a relatively time-consuming (one to three weeks of work comprising at least a few hours a day) take-home software engineering project. For the most recent, this meant implementing a highly non-trivial set of algorithms described in a research paper, writing a summary and critique of that paper, implementing an alternative algorithm of my own design, assessing the performance of these algorithms using various statistical techniques, writing documentation for these algorithms, and recording a 10-minute video describing all of this. Two of these positions also required I participate in brief technical "exams", personality assessments, and similar.
Every time I feel very good about my odds. Nice things are said about my performance on the exams and projects, and I make it through several rounds of virtual and at times in-person interviews. Yet every one of these has ended in one of the following three ways:

For two of those positions, I received an e-mail after a couple of months of silence letting me know that the position had been closed as the group was re-assessing their needs.
For three of those positions, I received an e-mail letting me know that the group/department/university had decided they no longer had the budget to hire someone for the position. In neither case had salary ever been discussed, and I never on my application or in an interview mentioned my salary expectations.
For the most recent position, I was told that the department had instituted a hiring freeze, that the position was effectively closed for at least several months, and that I "may be contacted" at some point in the distant future.

I understand that things come up, budgets (especially in academia) tend to be tight, and needs change. But after six occurrences of this, a ton of work invested, and a substantial amount of money spent, I cannot help but feel that I have done something wrong, or that there is something else going on here. At the very least, I cannot continue to invest this much time and money into the job search without considering the possibility, improbable as it may be. After discussing this with a former advisor, we concluded that it is at least possible I am being "let down gently".
Are employers often untruthful for the sake of "letting applicants down gently"? Is it possible that I have done something wrong here? Is it this common for this much time and energy to be invested, only for the position to vaporize?
I have tried determining whether anyone had, in fact, been hired for any of these roles, but was unable to come to any conclusion. I feel that it would be incredibly inappropriate to pose this as a question to any of the aforementioned employers.

You're already doing the work for free, so why would they hire you? More seriously, I've never heard of an interviewing process where you'd need to work several weeks, especially for an entry level job. And frankly, I'm amazed that someone actually even does that. Are these six all for the same university?

@Berend These are for six different universities. I've talked with a few people about this, and evidently it is a very standard (but in my opinion ridiculous) part of the interview process for positions such as these. All have been reputable (e.g., Northeastern University, Dartmouth College, Ohio State). To be fair, perhaps I'm putting more effort into the projects than need be. They are, however, always fairly non-trivial, and would still take a not insignificant amount of time to achieve the bare minimum. I've been given between 1 and 3 weeks to complete these, typically closer to 3.

VTC: The only people that can answer this question, are the people who gave the rejection notce. At best all we can offer is speculation.

@IntegerEuler - Even reputable institutions can have disrepetuable people working for them. The process sounds like you are doing a whole bunch of unpaid work and then once they have the work, they are giving you your marching orders. There are various posts online about how people have had similar experiences and have taken steps to ensure they are paid for their work.

@TheDemonLord Thanks for the input. Is there any way to delicately go about investigating this? I feel that inquiring with the hiring team would at best be insulting, as I can think of no way to probe this without suggesting the possibility of deceit. I fear burning bridges, especially given that the probability of their being untruthful is quite low.

@IntegerEuler - realistically, No. What I would suggest is to ensure that next time you are given a project, you deliver it in such a way as to retain control over it - so that if you dont get the position, you revoke access - if they complain, you can demand payment for your services (at contracting rates)

As an employer (but not an academic one) I can tell you I have never said "actually I won't be hiring anyone" when the truth was "I hired someone else". The actual reason they don't hire you isn't very important - the amount of effort you're expected to put into applying and being considered is.

FWIW, I don't think my academic department has been able to hire a new faculty member within roughly the last decade. Every time the college lets us potentially look for a hire, the overall process takes a year or two, and within that time another hiring freeze is put in place (resetting the whole thing).

"required flying across the country at my expense" absolutely do not do this. If they want to bring you out for an interview, they should pay your expenses. If they are not willing to pay your expenses, don't go.

"...substantial amount of money spent...". How much money have you spent on those "interviews" ? It could be a scam for the interviewers or the companies to ask you to spend money in order to proceed with the job interviews. No legit companies or recruiters would ever ask interviewees to pay them money for you to have the interviews. Please watch out for scams.

@Job_September_2020 While the universities themselves have not asked for money, is has cost me on the order of $1,500 each time in flights, accommodation, food, etc., which is a far from insignificant sum for me at the moment. I'm near the American west coast, and both of these have happened to take place on the east coast, flights between which are costly even at the most economic of airlines.

@IntegerEuler, Sorry to hear about that. Usually, if you have on-campus or in-person interviews with private or for-profit companies, they will pay for your travel cost, flight, hotel, food, etc...


Are employers often untruthful for the sake of "letting applicants down gently"?

It happens. Most employers will not give a reason at all since it just leads to pointless arguing and can create legal exposure. "We are out of money" is "safe" answer. You can't argue with it.

Is it possible that I have done something wrong here?

Sure, it's possible. But if and what we really can't tell without being there. Personally, I don't think so. If you screw up somewhere along the way, it ends typically much earlier in the process.

Is it this common for this much time and energy to be invested, only for the position to vaporize?

No. The amount of time and work you were asked to invest is highly unusual for industry jobs. I'm not that familiar with university hiring any more, but at the schools I worked, we would not have done that. Again, this may be a university thing, but in industry positions rarely "vaporize". It's a pain in a neck to get a req (job requisition) approved and once you have it, you hold on to it.
My advise would be to take a shot at non-university jobs. There is plenty of research in industry and there all kinds of research labs that are half way between industry and university. Depends a bit on your country though.

Yep, academics don't have a vested interest in getting workers. In my limited experience with them most things have fallen through.

"We found another candidate we like better" is also a safe answer in most cases. Would you really rather hear that one? Your response should be the same either way: shrug, grumble a bit, and continue your job search.

You aren't applying for jobs, you are doing work for free.
I don't know where you are, but your interview process is strange.  No one needs you to do the work to hire you.  They are just using you.
Besides this, no one will ever tell you why they aren't hiring you.  There is no upside to the hiring company, only downsides.  Get used to this.


For the most recent, this meant implementing a highly non-trivial set of algorithms described in a research paper, writing a summary and critique of that paper, implementing an alternative algorithm of my own design, assessing the performance of these algorithms using various statistical techniques, writing documentation for these algorithms, and recording a 10-minute video describing all of this. Two of these positions also required I participate in brief technical "exams", personality assessments, and similar.

That sounds like a lot of work... How many hours did you spend being scammed for free labor on that job interview project?

As someone who has been interviewing people a lot recently. We do 3 interviews at most, 1st is a quick phone screen. 2nd is a 1 hour tech interview, after which we know if you have the skills we expect for the position.
Finally an in-person multi-hour interview (Which includes a more comprehensive tech interview). Is expensive for us (Due to the number of people on our end involved/expense of room/travel/dining of our interviewee). Which is 50% us making a final assessment, and 50% us selling the position to you (interviews are a 2 way street after all).
After which the decision is made over a 30 minute discussion. Unanimous for hiring, single dissent == not hired. Don't really need longer than that.
Based on my experience, more interviews than that is just a waste of time/money for everyone involved.
All in all it is 2 Hours remote + 4 hours in-person, and some time for you to prepare a presentation on something cool that you have done in the past (Passion project, school project, something from a previous company that you can talk about etc...).
We don't make you work on anything real (IE beneficial to us) during the interview process as that is very, very dishonest/scummy.

TLDR: It should take less than 10 hours of your time to interview at a company... A maximum of 2 hours of your time at a company that you clearly weren't a good fit.
